# primefaces calendar change event with validator problem

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces

I am using a `<p:calendar />` with a custom validator. I want the validator to be trigered by the `change` event.

Furthermore I use a date pattern which includes time (`dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm`).
If time is used the component acts different compared to simple date usage. When selecting a date in the popup date picker, the popup itself does not auto-close because one probably want to select the time subsequently.

In my setting I need to update the message and the calendar to get correct validation presentation (info in the message and red border on calendar).
But the update closes the date picker so I need to open it twice to set date and time. Anyway it still gets worse because the time slider actually fires a change event on *every* step so that I simply can not use the slider (I would need to open the picker thirty times to set it to half past twelve).

I see the contradicting requirements (update component vs. staying popup) but have no solution. I am grateful for any advice.

```
<p:message 
    id="id_message" 
    for="id_calendar" />
<p:calendar
    id="id_calendar"
    value="#{backingBean.date}"
    pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm">
    <f:validator 
        validatorId="myValidator" />
    <p:ajax 
        event="change" 
        update="id_message id_calendar"/>
</p:calendar>
```

Comment: A slight improvement would be using a `delay="500"` on the `p:ajax`

Answer (score 0):

Great advice, thank you @Kukeltje for the comment.

I go a little further and set `delay="10000"` so that the popup virtually never auto closes in a normal user interaction. My users are accustomed that the popup does not auto close because of the standard date and time input behaviour of the `<p:calendar />` component anyway.

That has done the trick for me.

**Update**

Maybe 10 seconds is just not such a good idea because when entering a date manually it takes 10 seconds as well to trigger validation...

Comment: Do you know why it worked for you? Why should popup closing matter? The update happens after the date is set in the backing bean and validation should then remove the red border, right? Setting the delay didn't work for me.